# How to identify the correct definition of a word in a sentence, Python?

Tags: python, text, nlp

How do you identify the correct definition of a word in a sentence using NLP in Python?

For example, you have two sentences that use the verb 'get' with two different definitions:

1. He **got** a bike for his birthday. (get = to obtain, receive, or be given something)
2. He **got** a taxi from the station. (get = to use a particular vehicle to travel somewhere)

Can anyone point me in the right direction with an example of code in Python, or even an app/software that can already do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Word Sense Disambiguation` domain.

Have a look at this library: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd